# Encoding error when not outputting to terminal

Tags: python, shell, pipe, pipeline

I am wondering why capturing (piping) stdout results in an empty file, while *not capturing it* results in normal output. I don't get an encoding error when outputting to terminal. Only when piping the output.

Does the encoding change when outputting to a pipe instead of the terminal? Maybe the terminal can signal supported encodings, while a pipe defaults to ASCII?

**Piping the output**

```
$ curl -s 'https://www.sunwind.no/Outlet/'  | html2text | wc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe5' in position 212: ordinal not in range(128)
      0       0       0
```

**Not capturing the output**

```
curl -s 'https://www.sunwind.no/Outlet/' | html2text
  * [Forsiden](https://www.sunwind.no/)
  * [Logg inn](/login/)
  * [Registrer meg](https://www.sunwind.no/register/)

[![](https://www.sunwind.no/images/flag/NORW0001.GIF)](https://www.sunwind.no
"Klikk her for å gå til forsiden")
[![](https://www.sunwind.no/images/flag/SWDN0001.GIF)](https://www.sunwind.se
"Klikk her for å gå til Sunwinds svenske side")
[![](https://www.sunwind.no/images/flag/FINL0001.GIF)](https://www.sunwind.fi
"Klikk her for å gå til Sunwinds finske side")
[![](https://www.sunwind.no/images/flag/DENM0001.GIF)](https://www.sunwind.no/page/?pid=132
"Klikk her for å gå til Sunwinds danske side")
[![](https://www.sunwind.no/images/flag/UK0001.GIF)](https://www.sunwind.no/en/
"Klikk her for å gå til engelsk side")

[ ![](https://www.sunwind.no/images/Logo.png)](https://www.sunwind.no/)

![](https://www.sunwind.no/images/Enjoy_Brun_logo_text.png)

  * __ 0 **kr 0,-**

Nylig lagt til i handlevognen

[Gå til handlekurven](https://www.sunwind.no/account/basket/)

[ Sunwind.no](https://www.sunwind.no/)

  * Alle produkter __

##### **[KJØKKEN OG GASS](/product/content/show/?cap=7&KJOKKEN-OG-GASS) **

    * [__Gasskomfyr](https://www.sunwind.no/product/category/?cap=13)
    * [__Innbyggingsovn gass](https://www.sunwind.no/product/category/?cap=14)
    * [__Gasstopp](https://www.sunwind.no/product/category/?cap=15)
    * [__Gasskjøleskap](https://www.sunwind.no/product/category/?cap=63)
    * [__Kjøleskap 12 volt](https://www.sunwind.no/product/category/?cap=148)
    * [__Kjøle- og fryseboks](https://www.sunwind.no/product/category/?cap=144)
    * [__Kjøkkenvifte](https://www.sunwind.no/product/category/?cap=65)
    * [__Tilbehør og turutstyr](https://www.sunwind.no/product/category/?cap=97)
    * [__Gassutstyr og monteringsmateriell](https://www.sunwind.no/product/category/?cap=20)


etc
```

The `html2text` alias is a one-line python command:

```
alias html2text='python -c "import sys,html2text;sys.stdout.write(html2text.html2text(sys.stdin.read().decode(\"utf-8\")))"'
```

This is the first time I have encountered this behaviour. Is my one-liner somehow not handling piped output?

Comment: Try unsetting `LC_ALL` before running... `unset LC_ALL; curl ...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Same error.

Comment: Does your python command run python 2 or 3? There are issues with text encoding, but some useful defaults where added in python 3 so maybe you don't have to change your program.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson You were right that installing Python 3 fixed the problem. So thanks for that. But the question of _why_ the behaviour of python 2 is how it is still remains :-)

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it seems that googling "python unicode" brings up useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my 2 cents, as input data is properly decoded (`.decode(\"utf-8\")`), output data need to be encoded as well (`.encode(\"utf-8\")`). So the working version of your one liner should be as below. The [why](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) question need long time to study.

```
alias html2text='python2 -c "import sys,html2text;sys.stdout.write(html2text.html2text(sys.stdin.read().decode(\"utf-8\")).encode(\"utf-8\"))"'
curl -s 'https://www.sunwind.no/Outlet/'  | html2text | wc
    764    1839   29329
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the encoding to the wrong part when I tried earlier. But why does it work when not piping? Does the encoding change when outputting to a pipe instead of the terminal? Maybe the terminal can signal supported encodings, while a pipe defaults to ASCII?

Comment: It works with piping. I tried with `curl -s 'https://www.sunwind.no/Outlet/'  | html2text | grep __` and found that grep can handle the output from html2txt. I think you are correct about terminal can support the encoding by html2txt. I also think the pipe is just stream of bytes. And programs in pipe need to have same understanding (encoding/decoding method) about the byte stream.

Comment: Sorry, writing on the internet is hard. 'it' referred to the original version without explicit encoding of the resulting stream. I know your version works with piping, while mine didn't.

Comment: Sorry that I mistakenly piped through grep without using the original version. Have a good day. :)